# Horizontal alignment of subscript and superscript - xetex

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I want to horizontally align my subscripts and superscripts. I'm using XeTex with the Cambria Math font, and I'm rather new to Latex so I don't quite know if the problem is with the font, XeTex itself or some package i'm using...

Here is an example :

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
% Set fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Cambria}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
% Set margins
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% No alinea
% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent (too big in 1.5 spacing)
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % No alinea

\date{}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\graphicspath{{../img/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}

% 1.5 line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage[autolinebreaks,framed, useliterate]{mcode}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    literate=::1,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}
}


\usepackage[                              % PDF format config.
      unicode=true,                       % Unicode encoding.
      bookmarks=true,                     % Bookmarks in PDF.
      bookmarksnumbered=true,             % Numberred bookmarks.
      bookmarksopenlevel=3,               % Shows up to subsections when opening PDF.
      pdfborder= {0 0 0},                 % Removes the border around links.
      backref=page,                      % Removes the links from bibliography to main text.
      colorlinks=false,                   % Colouring the links.
      linktoc=page,                       % In ToC, only page numbers are links, not section titles.
      linkcolor=red,                      % Colour of links (section numbers, pages, ...).
      citecolor=blue,                     % Colour of links to bibliography (citations).
      urlcolor=blue]                      % Colour of URLs.
      {hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \rightmark} %section
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark} % chapter
\fancyhead[LO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}


\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}



% ****** BEGIN DOCUMENT *******
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  w_0^0(x) &= f(x) \qquad w_0^1(x) &&= f(1-x) \\
  w_1^0(x) &= g(x) \qquad w_1^1(x) &&= -g(1-x)
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the subscripts and superscripts 0 and 1 are not horizontally aligned.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The behavior is usually wanted.

Comment: well is there any way to override it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @egreg pointed out, what you noticed is considered *good* typography. But if you insist on getting the sub- and superscripts horizontally aligned, then there is a quick solution: Just add an empty `{}` to the right of your `w`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Cambria}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  w{}_0^0(x) &= f(x)  & \qquad w{}_0^1(x) &= f(1-x) \\
  w{}_1^0(x) &= g(x)  &        w{}_1^1(x) &= -g(1-x)
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned]

Please note that I’ve changed your `alignat` to the structure which is meant to be used. I provide this manual solution to *discourage* you to do so.

Additional notes: You have many problems in your preamble.

- For a MWE, you don’t need to provide us with unrelated packages. Please keep your code simple next time.
- If you are already using `\usepackage{setspace}`, then don’t use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`. Instead, use `\setstretch{1.5}`.
- It’s better to load the `hyperref` package last.